# How to search through every part of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to ignore any links in a part of HTML, and get anything that does not have a link to do my function.

What I have so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // search through paragraphs
     $("p").each(function() {
          // if there is not a link
          if (!$(this).find('a').hasClass('external-link')) {
                 // do my function
          }
     })
})
```

My problem I am having, is that if there is a link in a line, but also something I want to capture in the same line it does not work, as it ignores the entire line.

Here is link to a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oz1ydf3w/2/), which hopefully will let you see what I am trying to do.

Thank you in advance

---

Edit:

I may have worded the question slightly confusingly.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is:

```
<p>Link to ignore: <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">news</a>
Link to create: news </p>
```

My code would search through the `<p>` tags for "news", and then create a link to the website. However, I do not want to create a link on top of an existing link. My current code, would ignore everything within the `<p>` tags, because there is a link there already.

Comment: "Lines" don't exist as part of the document structure, so what you're trying to do doesn't really make sense as an operation on an HTML DOM.

Comment: "Lines" might be the wrong word for it. Wasn't sure how to describe it. Maybe between HTML tags would be better

Comment: You want to ignore the links that have the class .external-links and that are inside p tag?

Comment: Well then you can work your way through the text nodes that are *between* the `<a>` tags, and pay attention to only some of them based on what you want to accomplish (which isn't totally clear). The jQuery `.contents()` API may be of interest if that sounds close to what you want.

Comment: Is there a pattern to how things are set up? As in, could you grab all the child elements of the p tag and put them in an array, then remove those that are links?

Comment: The document is a tree structure and exists in the browser differently than what you would see in your editor. Elements in the document have children and sometimes siblings and this concept might help in clearing up what exactly it is you are attempting.

Comment: Yes, although if there is something I want to capture within the same <p> tags, I don't want to ignore it. The JSFiddle might clear up my unclear question

Comment: I don't get it, if the element doesn't have that class, perform a replace, but none of the other anchors match the regex, so there won't be any replace no matter what you do ?

Comment: @adeneo there is the first "news" which already has a link - and as there is already a link, I do not want to replace it, just ignore it (if you inspect element, there would be two links there)

Comment: Well, yes, two links don't have the class, but none of them contains `news`, so they don't match the regex ?

Comment: Anyway, here's how you'd do it -> http://jsfiddle.net/oz1ydf3w/3/

Comment: @adeneo, the two google links were just random catches. The main links I was concerned about were the "news" links. So the code I'm trying to achieve is to ignore the first link (so I don't create a link on top of it), while creating a link on the second "news"

Comment: What do you want, you are pretty unclear :D

Comment: Well, I believe I just gave you the answer as to how to do that, target the anchors and replace the outerHTML instead.

Comment: @adeneo But there is no anchor on the last news!?! %)P

Comment: I've edited my question to hopefully portray my question a bit better, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Oh, it's clearer now, what you really should ask for is a regular expression that catches strings that *are not* inside anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to ignore the anchors so you don't create new anchors inside existing anchors.
This targets the textNodes only

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").contents().each(function(_, node) {
        if ( node.nodeType && node.nodeType === 3 ) {
            var regex = /(news)/g;
            var value = node.nodeValue.replace(regex, '<a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/$1">$$&</a>');
            if (value.match(regex)) {
                var wrap  = document.createElement('span');
                wrap.innerHTML = value
                node.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, node);
                node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oz1ydf3w/11/)

To keep the dollarsign, you have to  do  `$$` as the dollarsign has special meaning in a regular expression.

Comment: Except it doesnt work! %)P There should be a "$&" as the last "news". Enlighten me.

Comment: Oh, so you want to keep the actual dollarsign now? You realize that the dollarsign is a variable in the regex ?

Comment: Wow, that goes over my head. It's all good. Chrome sometimes does not show the anchor `href` hovered preview...was too lazy. You did it! Congrats. ( Was thinking you should give him your mind to stop the confusion on asking anywaayyy ).

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach and extended jQuery's function prototype -

```
$.fn.extend({
    replace: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
                search: ''
            };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var string = $(this).html();
            //var regex = /(search)/g;
            var regex = /(^|\s)news/;
            //var regex = new RegExp("(^|\s)" + options.search);
            console.log(regex);
            var replace_text = string.replace(regex, '<a href = "https://www.bbc.co.uk/$1">$&</a>');
            $(this).html(replace_text);
        });
    }
});


$('p').replace({search: 'news'});
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oz1ydf3w/15/)

```
$('p').replace();
```

Changing the regex slightly to account for a space (instead of a greater than bracket) at the beginning of 'news' allows a single neat call to the extended function. Also updated to make the function more useful, allowing the user to pass arguments to the function. Still not perfect - a work in progress.

Comment: I made a small change to the regex @adeneo and it works better, but still not perfect. The link for the searched text is screwed up because it doesn't end in '/news`. I have to run off for a bit but will revisit as soon as I can.

Comment: I noticed, and it seems to work for the example given, but if you change the anchor to `<a> news</a>` it still fails, but that's probably not very relevant, and the OP seems to have left the building anyway !

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you for your input! Is there any chance of not changing the regex? As it wouldn't work for example if I had (news) , or anything in front of the 'n'

Comment: I was going to experiment with passing the value to the function but have not had the time to go back to it and refactor. Any good function would allow you to pass arguments instead of hard coding items. Given that I would go with @adeno's answer. I will try to refactor this at my earliest opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by looking at the childnodes of each `p` and grabbing the ones that do not have a class of `external-link`:

```
var otherText = [];
$("p").each(function(){
    console.log(this.childNodes);
    var kids = this.childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++)
    {
        if(!($(kids[i]).hasClass("external-link")))
        {
            otherText.push(kids[i]); //or do what you want with the node here
        }
    }
});
console.log("other Text", otherText);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvan525r/)